# DROP FUNCTION doesn't work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a function and I already have that function in the database. To bypass this I'm using drop function, but I still keep getting 'theres already object named 'getCost' in the database'. What might be the cause?

Query:

```
USE DWDB_PROPER;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.getCost', N'TF') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION dbo.getCost;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION getCost(@person VARCHAR(10), @month TINYINT, @year SMALLINT, @Category    VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
--function body here
```

Comment: the problems is in your If condition see the LolCoder answer

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but why does your `CREATE FUNCTION` not explicitly say `dbo.getCost`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following query:

```
USE DWDB_PROPER;
GO
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'dbo.getCost') 
    AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF')
)
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.getCost
GO
CREATE FUNCTION getCost(@person VARCHAR(10), @month TINYINT, @year SMALLINT, @Category    VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
```

Answer (score 6):

yours is a scalar function as it is only returning a value so in the if clause you should mention FN instead of TF.Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
USE DWDB_PROPER;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.getCost', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION dbo.getCost;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION getCost(@person VARCHAR(10), @month TINYINT, @year SMALLINT, @Category       VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
--function body here
```

Your are returning a single value instead of a table .So RETURNS int is a multiselect Scalar Function
where as Returns Table is a Table Value function

Comment: Thank you, I'm quite new to tsql and I make stupid mistakes like that quite often :)